# Multiple edge loops and appear in my model after I added Shade smooth and subdivision Modifier

Tags: modeling, sculpting, edges, subdivision-surface

I'm very new to blender and I have been following this tutorial where i get to build the model below....everything looked perfectly fine in edit mode until I was to prepare my objects for sculpting by adding a subdivision modifier (up to four on each object) while following the tutorial. I moved on to the next step which is UV unwrapping only to discover i had what seems to be like millions of edge loops that weren't there before, now. I have tried using unsubdivide but it comes out looking damaged with some [image: This is the image after i tried to unsubdivide]triangular faces(I had only quads while building)
[image: This is the image before i tried to unsubdivide. it has like a million edge loops that weren't there before][image: This is what the image is supposed to originally look like with few edge loops]

Comment: Please add a link to the tutorial you are following. It would also help if you shared your blend file with the reference image packed into it via File > External Data > Pack Resources. You can then share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.